# Is this c++17 template type deduction a bug in MSVC?

Tags: c++, c++17

Please see this code - I simplified it to minimum from my real code:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<auto First, auto Last>
class EnumIterator
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(First), decltype(Last)>::value == true,
        "First and Last must be of the same enum class type");

public:
    using EnumType = decltype(First);
};

enum class E1 { e1_a, e1_b };
using E1_It = EnumIterator<E1::e1_a, E1::e1_b>;

enum class E2 { e2_a, e2_b };
using E2_It = EnumIterator<E2::e2_a, E2::e2_b>;

E2_It::EnumType e = E2::e2_a;
```

On Visual Studio 2017, lang set to c++17 compilation fails with:

```
error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'E2' to 'EnumIterator<E1::e1_a,E1::e1_b>::EnumType'
note: Conversion to enumeration type requires an explicit cast (static_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast)
```

I verified the same code compiles on wandbox.com and it compiles ok.
Note, comment out the line with `using E1_It` and now it compiles with MSVC.

Did I find a compiler bug, or am I doing something obviously wrong?

Comment: I would guess so. It seems to compile with version `19.20` and later. [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/VmFHVa)

Comment: This behavior is so obviously wrong—note the type name in the error message—that I’m not sure why it’s worth a question.